# Ubuntu 19.10 installed OK, but has Thunderbolt 3 docking station issues

Tags: multiple-monitors, lenovo, thinkpad, thunderbolt

As stated in the title, 19.10 is installed and runs well on my [Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 2](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-extreme-gen-2) notebook PC. However, I can't get external displays to work through my Thunderbolt 3 docking station.

My mouse and keyboard connected to the docking station both work, and Ubuntu sees both external monitors connected through the docking station (they are listed under devices and I can attempt to use them). However, even though I have used [boltctl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/boltctl.1.html) to confirm the Thunderbolt dock is enrolled and authorized, the displays don't work.

I saw something somewhere that stated that enabling "BIOS Assist Mode" might help, however I am unable to change that setting in the BIOS (perhaps because Windows is controlling it).

Does anyone have any additional ideas?

Additional information:

Docking station model: ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Workstation Dock/Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2 - Type 40AN

Additional troubleshooting: I do not have a Thunderbolt to Display Port cable to test with, however HDMI directly into the laptop works fine. Attempting to use HDMI from the Thunderbolt dock does not work.

Comment: 1) What's the make and model of the dock? I've seen docks work AOK with USB but fail with Thunderbolt 3, so I feel obliged to ask. 2) If you bypass the dock and attach directly from laptop to just one monitor (as in page 10 of https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/p1gen2_x1extreme_ug_v2_en.pdf) , does that work, checking each monitor? Please click [edit] and add those facts to the question. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: A Dell user updated UEFI & firmware for his dock and then after reboot, it worked. You should be able to update from withing Ubuntu. https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/ UEFI & Dock updates: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2431141

Comment: @oldfred : To test fwupd do I just need to run the same commands that you recommended in that post? (sudo fwupdmgr get-devices
sudo fwupdmgr get-updates) . I looked through the list of updates on the page for Lenovo devices and I see things for the X1 Extreme, but I do not see anything specifically listed as being for the X1 Extreme Gen 2. I have never used this utility and so want to clarify, if I run those commands it should look at my hardware and only pull updates specific to my laptop, correct?

Comment: That is my understanding. My system is not yet supported, so have not run those commands. IF when you get devices, if not shown then I would expect update to not run. But if it supported older version, I would then they should also support newer versions. It is more that old systems are not added.

Comment: Thank  you. I will try that a little later today. I will run fwupdmgr get-devices and if it lists stuff for me I will run it with "get-updates".

Comment: I tried that and fwupdmgr found no updates for my dock.